# MongoDB aggregation: how to group/bucket documents in interval with non numeric limits?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have the following data in MongoDB:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "room": "A",
    "state": "open",
    "temp": 22,
    "timestamp": T1
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "room": "A",
    "state": "open",
    "temp": 25,
    "timestamp": T2
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "room": "A",
    "state": "close",
    "temp": 27,
    "timestamp": T3
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "room": "A",
    "state": "open",
    "temp": 22,
    "timestamp": T4
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "room": "A",
    "state": "close",
    "temp": 22,
    "timestamp": T5
  }
]
```

I would like to group the documents from the first "open" until the following "close" and compute the average temperature, opening time and closing time.

```json
[
  {
    "room": "A",
    "avgTemp": 25,
    "openTimestamp": T1
    "closeTimestamp": T3
  },
  {
    "room": "A",
    "avgTemp": 22,
    "openTimestamp": T4
    "closeTimestamp": T5
  } 
]
```

`timestamp` is an actual timestamp, which I replaced with T<sub>x</sub> for ease of reference. Every document has its own autogenerated `_id`.

I have thought of using `$setWindowFields` to add a new field `closeId`, then group by `closeId`. Ideally, something like this:

```
$setWindowFields: {
  partitionBy: {
    room: "$room"
  },
  sortBy: {
    timestamp: 1,
  },
  output: {
    closeId: {
      $first: "$_id",
      window: {
        documents: ["current", "unbounded"],
        filter: {
          $eq: ["$state", "close"]
        }
      },
    },
  },
},
$group: {
  $_id: {
    "closeId": "$closeId",
    "room": "$room"
  },
  avgTemp: { $avg: "$temp" },
  openTimestamp: { $first: "$timestamp" },
  closeTimestamp: { $last: "$timestamp" }
}
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to filter the window like I did in the example query above, and don't know how to get the desired result.

Can anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: How would ```openTimestamp``` and ```closeTimestamp``` calculated in result ?

Comment: They are the `timestamp` of the first `open` state and the `close` state respectively.

Comment: Hi @ray thanks for the feedback, I have edited the question. About the ambiguity, T1, T2 and T3 all belong to the same group. Every document is a snapshot of the state of a room, so there can be multiple consecutive "open" status for the same room.